# How to use setLayoutParams

Tags: android-linearlayout

I am waiting to expand and contract a linear layout.

The linear layout height will be set to `0dp` pixels in the beginning and once a user selects a certain button then that layout height will be expanded to `MATCH_PARENT`.

Once the user selects the button again the linear layout is given a height of `0dp` again.

Please any help will be awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like below to set the height to 0

```
// Get your linearlayout
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylinearlayout);
// Gets the layout params that will allow you to resize the layout
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
// Changes the height and width to the specified *pixels*
params.height = 0;
```